# UMPU versus UMP

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I feel like this is a really basic question, but its been low-key bothering me.  I understand that UMP tests are UMPU tests, but that not all UMPU tests are UMP.  What is a specific example of a UMPU test that is not UMP?  It seems like UMP tests are the ideal tests.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What is an UMP? What is a UMPU?

Comment: Two-sided t-test for the two-sided alternative is UMPU but not UMP (there exists no UMP test in that case). @copper.hat UMP stands for uniformly most powerful, UMPU is UMP unbiased.

Comment: Maybe Cross Validated might be a better target? (Thanks @guy.)

Comment: UMP is an optimal test whenever it exists. Often the next best thing is UMPU which is what we search for when UMP is not available.

Comment: So a UMPU is uniformly most powerful test out of the unbiased tests, and a UMP you is the uniformly most powerful test in general?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure if you're still curious about this subject, but I happen to know one example. So, UMP test is basically a test that has the size of $\alpha$ and has the strongest power among the ones with the same size. Let's take a look at an example below.
$$
\text{Find UMP test of $H_0: \mu = \mu_0, H_1: \mu > \mu_0 $ from }X_1, \dots, X_n \overset{i.i.d}{\sim} N(\mu, 1)
$$
Let us be given an arbitrary $\mu_1 > \mu_0$, then by [Neyman Pearson Lemma](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/45587/18-441Spring-2002/NR/rdonlyres/Mathematics/18-441Statistical-InferenceSpring2002/42BEBDE5-7C30-4C3F-8217-E9BEF04D700E/0/ps8.pdf), the MP test is as below,
$$
\phi(x) = \begin{cases}
1, \bar{x} - \mu_0 \geq z_{\alpha}/\sqrt{n}\\
0, \bar{x} - \mu_0 < z_{\alpha}/\sqrt{n}
\end{cases}
$$
Fortunately, this test works for all $\mu$'s not just this single $\mu_1$. So, we can find UMP by Neyman Pearson Lemma when the MP test does not depend on the alternative parameter space. I recommend you try the same thing when $H_0(-): \mu \leq \mu_0$ with the same alternative hypothesis. The test result does not change. However, the result is not in 'two-sided test' where $H_0: \mu = \mu_0, H_1: \mu \neq \mu_0$. UMP Test does not exist in this one, but UMPU does. The conditions for UMPU is as below,
$$
\mathbb{E}_{\theta_0}\phi^*(X)=\alpha, [\frac{d}{d\theta}\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\phi^*(X)]_{\theta=\theta_0} = 0
$$
$$
\forall \phi: \mathbb{E}_{\theta_0}\phi(X) = \alpha, [\frac{d}{d\theta}\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\phi(X)]_{\theta=\theta_0} = 0 \\
\mathbb{E}_{\theta_1}\phi^*(X) \geq \mathbb{E}_{\theta_1}\phi(X)
$$

The UMP does not but the UMPU $\phi^*$ does exist in this case. More information about UMPU can be found in *Testing Statistical Hypothesis 3rd ed. [E. L. Lehmann & J. P. Romano]*